# How do I validate the values from a set of key-value pairs?

Tags: f#

How do I validate the values from a set of key-value pairs?

```
[<Test>]
let ``player has connected row`` () =
    let grid = [ for i in 0..8 -> (i, true) ] |> Map.ofSeq
    let rows = grid |> Seq.chunkBySize 3 |> Seq.toList
    rows.Head.[0..] ** verify all values from list is true**  |> should equal true
```

1. Do I really need to convert the array generated by chunkBySize to a list?

> |> Seq.toList

2. How do I verify that all values from key-value pairs are set to true from the row?
3. How could I validate this for all rows?

NOTE:

I am new to F# so please forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the `Seq.forall` function:

```
rows.Head |> Seq.forall (fun kvp -> kvp.Value) |> should equal true
```

Here, `forall` will return `true` if the specified condition holds for all inputs in the sequence (in the condition, we just return the Boolean value). To do this for all rows, you can use `Seq.forall` again:

```
rows |> Seq.forall (fun row -> 
  row |> Seq.forall (fun kvp -> kvp.Value)) |> should equal true
```

This no longer requires converting the input to a list, because it is using just `Seq` functions.

You could also use ordinary `for` loops and check the values separately:

```
for row in rows do
  for kvp in row do
    kvp.Value |> should equal true
```

I guess that this might not make testing purists happy, because we are doing the checking in F# code rather than specifying it as a single declarative assertion. Though I'm not sure if there is any nicer way of doing this and I'd probably write it using the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas on how to do this for all rows? This is really foreign to me.

Comment: More samples just added :)